# Strange controller name Content

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller

I am using my own controller factory and sometimes in function

```
public IController CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, string controllerName)
```

controllerName parameter assigned with value "Content" which I can't find in my CompositionContainer.
That's why I have 2 question:

1. What is "Content" how can I filter it?
2. Is there some same good sample to show how to correctly override CreateController?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) What is "Content" how can i filter it?

Maybe a request was made to `/Content/Foo`

> 2) Is there some same good sample to show how to correctly override CreateController?

There are many examples out there showing how this could be done with different DI frameworks.  Here's a [sample implementation](http://joelabrahamsson.com/entry/really-simple-ioc-with-aspnet-mvc-and-structuremap) with StructureMap.

Comment: thank you for quick response and link,i searched /Content but not found it (in my project only 2 controllers home and login that why i am confused)

Comment: Yes, but maybe in your views you have some static resources like images, css, js files which are included and which might contain this.

Comment: Yes i found its image Content\img\my.png but how can i filter it? I dont get it...

Comment: Ill fix it by this line: routes.IgnoreRoute("Content/{*pathInfo}");